# Must a hyperbolic cone over Riemannian manifold be manifold? 

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

M is a hyperbolic cone over an n-1 dim Riemannian manifold N with $Ric(N) \ge  - \left( {n - 2} \right)$ ie
$M = R \times {}_{\cosh \left( t \right)}N$,Surely N is an Alexandrov space,must M be a manifold?must N be totally geodesic in M?If not,please give counterexamples and point out the singular points.

Comment: I don't understand what can go wrong, the metric you write is just a smooth warped product metric on $N\times\mathbb{R}$. Is the warping factor really $\cosh^2(t)$ ?

Comment: Sorry,I should write$M = R \times {}_{\cosh \left( t \right)}N$

Comment: It must be a manifold,please help me to close the question if you see it.

Comment: Since you raised this question, can you please tell us why it must be a manifold?